# How to check and install required .net version while installing bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Following is the code for my bootstrapper application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

<Bundle Name="BootstrapperSetup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="XYZ">
<Chain>   
  <ExePackage SourceFile="C:\SW\XYZ.exe" Compressed="yes"></ExePackage>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile= "C:\SW\ABC.msi" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="C:\SW\PQR.msi"  Compressed="yes" Name ="INSTALLDIR"/>    
</Chain>
</Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Before installing all the 3 packages, I want to check weather .net framework is installed on the machine or not, and if not, then i need to install it from another folder.

Please help me to do the needful.

Comment: Just a piece of advice: don't share the real GUIDs

Comment: @Yan, Any way to remove them from edit history?

Comment: @bendataclear, I'm not aware of any. It might be a good question for meta.stackoverflow.com, though

Comment: sorry..I was not knowing this. Thanks for the advice Yan!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of .NET you need you can add something like this to your chain:
`<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" />`

See here for other alternatives: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm.